# How to stop LiveWallpaper application when Wallpaper has changed

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I made a live wallpaper using opengl http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers. But when i chooses other wallpaper from list the wall paper has bean changed but my application is still running in background. Can any one suggest how to stop it when other wallpaper is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should stop automatically. If you have overridden `onDestroy()`, make sure you call `super.onDestroy()`.

If this doesn't help you can debug the live wallpaper with breakpoints after a call to `Debug.waitForDebugger()` to see which part of the app is still running.